# Where can I find a good overview of JASIG Central Authentication Service (CAS)?

Tags: cas

Where can I find a good overview of JASIG Central Authentication Service (CAS)? I know what it does (web app authentication and single sign-on), what I need is to know how it does it, i.e., I need a description of the interactions between the components and what pieces of information they exchange. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Technical+Overview

Also this might be of help: http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/cas/overview.php